# How do you say 'photographed by (someone)' in french?

Tags: grammaire

Could you please tell me how to say "photographed by...." in french.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! It's a great series of sites, but for the language sites, try looking things up in dictionaries first, and then asking here if there's something you don't understand. That would actually get you your answer a lot faster! Reverso is very good, so is wiktionary. The words you want are *être photographié par*, I believe. http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/photograph

Comment: Please look up the meaning of words or expressions in a dictionary first. If you did so and found nothing satisfactory, mention that in your question. Do give context for where you heard or saw the word.

Answer (score 1):

Pris(e) en photo par...

Photographié(e) par...